# Cannot zoom above whole country, java Google Maps V2

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am developing a project with a map displaying 100 markers in a country (Greece). When my map is open while launching application  in my mobile android phone, map zooms in Africa and in a tablet device it zooms in different location- country. This happens when my location is disabled through settings of my device. How can I set the map to zoom above whole country Greece when my map is loaded for first time? in any android device application is installed?

Please check my code below:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

/**
 * Check mMap. In case it is not null then setUpMap
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}
```

When I activate current location then it zooms on level 14 over my location. I need to keep this functionality when location setting are enabled.

```
// Show the current location in Google Map
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            // Zoom in the Google Map
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
map.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(xxxx,xxxx) , 14.0f) );
```

Where the coords, are for example the "middle" of Greece. And you will need to set some [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to know if is the first time that the app is open.

Comment: If worked for you will help to upvote and accept the answer to other people ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new version of API that calls you when the map is loaded:
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback.html
You can easily check if it is the first time by using a simple "singleton" or static variable.

About the Zoom, I would recomend you to build a LatLngBounds and zoom on it.
You can do this by iterating over all the Markers:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder zoomTo = LatLngBounds.builder();
for (Marker marker : markersList) {
     zoomTo.include(marker.getPosition());
}
final LatLngBounds workArea = zoomTo.build();
mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
     @Override
     public void onMapLoaded() {
           mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(workArea, 50));
           mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(null);
         }
 });
```